# A global disconnect

Tags: c++, qt

In the code I am maintaining I have just found the following line:

```
emit disconnect();
```

The method belongs to the `QObject` object. Of course `emit` is here for no reason, it also doesnt do anything since its an empty macro. I went to the `QObject` documentation and could not find what will happen when this method is called as a static one (`QObject::disconnect()`). From my observation, it seems like it has disconnected all signal/ slots connections in the caller class. Is this how it works when called like this?

Comment: `QObject::disconnect()` doesn't seem to be a signal, so combining it with `emit` keyword doesn't make sense to me. IMO it's just a function call that disconnects that object's signals from all receivers.

Comment: Please provide some context.  All of the static `QObject::disconnect` members require at least one parameter.  I think it more likely you're call [this non-static overload](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#disconnect-2) from within the context of some other non-static member function.

Comment: Yes, `emit` doesnt make sense. This was called from within a class, that inherits from `Qobject`- there is really not much more context to it. So if the `disconnect()` call has no parameters, what does it disconnect?

Comment: The keyword `emit` is a syntactic sugar and does nothing. The non static `disconnect` without parameter, remove all the connections to the object's signals. See the [Qt doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#disconnect) for more info.

Comment: No disconnect was provided, thats for sure. But looking at the header: `bool QObject::disconnect(const char *signal = nullptr, const QObject *receiver = nullptr, const char *method = nullptr) const`, it means that you can actually call `disconnect` with no parameters, since the default ones will be used.

Comment: @RomhaKorev yes, this was the case. Thank you.

Comment: Ok so `emit` here is just to confuse reader (trash it).

Comment: Yes, the `emit` keyword is here for no reason.